# How do I hide all previous message boxes before showing the target one

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, ajax

I use [the Pines Notify JQuery Plugin](http://pines.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pines/pnotify/raw-file/tip/index.html) to show message boxes to the user to show some alerts.

My question has two parts:

Before I show a message I try to remove all previous messages first, through the following method:

```
protected void HideStatus() {
    ScriptManager hs = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    string script = @"$.pnotify_remove_all();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Sticky Notice", script, true);
}
```

...but this doesn't work, and I'm not sure why.

The method I use to show my messages is as follows:

```
protected void ShowStatus(string message, string title, string type, string hide) {
    string script = @"
        $.pnotify({
            pnotify_title:'" + title + "',
            pnotify_text: '" + message + "',
            pnotify_type: '" + type + "',
            pnotify_opacity: .9,
            pnotify_hide: '" + hide + "'
        });";

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Sticky Notice", script, true);
}
```

---

The second problem is, I don't know where messages should appear (as in, "What is the best place for notifications to appear" as a user experience question).

Comment: Have you tried using the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock method?

Comment: What sort of javascript errors do you get when you call `hideStatus`?

Comment: The second part of your question is probably better asked on User Experience (http://ux.stackexchange.com/) or Programmers.

Comment: no error just when i call this method then `HideStatus()` then i call `ShowStatus()` no meesage appear.

Comment: @ w4ymo:yea i do , but still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Running `$.pnotify_remove_all();` should work. There is even an example (Remove All Notices) on the [demo page](http://pines.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pines/pnotify/raw-file/tip/index.html) for it...

Comment: I bet author is aware of existance of `$.pnotify_remove_all();` since it uses it in his code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following:

$(window).data("pnotify", []);

It worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

If those two scripts are in the same class, the seconnd one to run will overwrite the original because the key, `"Sticky Notice"` is the same for both `RegisterStartupScript()` calls. From what I remember, they have to be unique. Change one or both and they should work.